# Join with limit on right table

Tags: mysql, join, limit

Say I have two tables I want to join.
Categories:

```
id   name
----------
1    Cars
2    Games
3    Pencils
4    Books
```

And items:

```
id   categoryid   itemname
---------------------------
1    1            Ford
2    1            BMW
3    1            VW
4    2            Tetris
5    2            Pong
6    3            Foobar Pencil Factory
```

I want a query that returns the category and the last maximum N (for example: 2) itemname:

```
category.id category.name item.id item.itemname
-------------------------------------------------
1           Cars          2       BMW
1           Cars          3       VW
2           Games         4       Tetris
2           Games         5       Pong
3           Pencils       6       Foobar Pencil Factory
4           Books         NULL    NULL
```

I want write a query like below:

```
Select * From categories c
 Left Join (select * from items order by id desc) i
 On c.id=i=categoryid
  AND LIMIT 2 #comment: N=2 this line not supported
 Where i.categoryid = c.id
 Group By c.id
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not saying it's efficient, but it should work:

```
SELECT c.*, i.id, i.itemname
FROM categories c
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT i.*
   FROM items i
   LEFT JOIN items i2 ON i.categoryid = i2.categoryid AND i2.id > i.id
   GROUP BY i.id
   HAVING COUNT(*) < 2         # this 2 = N
  ) i ON c.id = i.categoryid
```

Comment: :I think your answer is correct but some field names are not correct. eg: i ON c.categoryid should be c.id and need to add i.categoryid here LEFT JOIN (SELECT i.id, i.itemname.Kindly verify

Comment: thanks, +1 because your answer work. but i am testing efficiency of this solution. if this is best efficient solution, i accept surely. i also wait for other suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a132/1

```
SELECT *
FROM Categories c 
LEFT JOIN -- Items i 
(
    SELECT * FROM Items WHERE LOCATE(id,
    (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(it.itemids) AS its
        FROM (
                SELECT (SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(id, CHAR(8))
                                                     ORDER BY id DESC), ',', 2)) AS itemids
                FROM Items
                GROUP BY categoryid
            ) it
    )) <> 0
) i
ON i.categoryid = c.id;
```

where N=2 is: SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(id, CHAR(8)) ORDER BY id DESC), ',', 2)

Because GROUP_CONCAT is by default sort ASC ; above will become SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(id, CHAR(8)) ), ',', -2). But GROUP_CONCAT result is truncated to max len 1024 (group_concat_max_len).

Comment: [Updated SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a132/5) to show correct rows and also included my query. Not too sure, but I would guess yours is faster than mine (where + subquery VS temporary).

Comment: I would test on very large set of data; depends on the table structure, indexes, other optimizations.